# Is the hyperbolic plane the only simply connected hyperbolic 2-manifold?

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

Let $S$ be a simply connected Riemannian 2-manifold with everywhere negative curvature.  Is $S$ necessarily diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: A few nitpicky comments: The existing answers assume (i) a _complete_ metric (ii) of _constant curvature_. The answer is "yes" even without these hypotheses, since a simply-connected surface is either $S^2$ or $\mathbf{R}^2$, and $S^2$ has no metric of negative curvature by Gauss-Bonnet. But $\mathbf{R}^2$ itself also admits a complete metric of (non-constant) negative curvature. :)

Comment: Where are these assumptions being made?  The Uniformization Theorem appears to apply to any simply connected Riemannian surface.

Comment: A Riemannian $2$-manifold $S$ with metric $g$ and a Riemann surface (i.e., $S$ equipped with a holomorphic structure compatible with $g$) are not obviously equivalent data. The wikipedia page cited describes a dictionary between Riemann surfaces and complete, constant curvature surfaces. By invoking this dictionary, the existing answers appear to assume more about the metric than is explicitly stated. But the question can be answered affirmatively without invoking uniformization.

Comment: What is the proof without uniformization?  Stating that simply connected surfaces are either $S^2$ or $\mathbf{R}^2$ essentially assumes the conclusion.

Comment: There's a topological classification of (second-countable) surfaces, and simple-connectedness should imply the surface is $S^2$ or $\mathbf{R}^2$. (Admittedly, I was tacitly assuming $S$ was the interior of a surface with boundary, and offhand don't see how to remove this hypothesis easily.) On a different tack, if one assumes completeness (but not constancy of curvature), the OP's question is answered affirmatively by the [Cartan-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan-Hadamard_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [geometric classification of surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem#Geometric_classification_of_surfaces) tells us that a simply connected Riemannian surface $S$ must be (up to diffeomorphism) the sphere $S^2$, the complex plane $\mathbf{C}$, or the hyperbolic plane $\mathbf{H}$. Given that $\mathbf{H}$ is the only one of these with negative curvature, $S$ must be the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Is it still true with 'up to isometry' instead of 'up to diffeomorphism'?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by [Uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be ultra clear about some issues related to the original question, there are **plenty** of simply connected surfaces of constant curvature K = 0 or K = -1 that are not isometric to either R<sup>2</sup> (K = 0) or H<sup>2</sup> (K = -1). Some of these are each the interior of a simple closed curve drawn on either R<sup>2</sup> or H<sup>2</sup>. Some others are each one side of an infinite simple arc drawn on R<sup>2</sup> or H<sup>2</sup> that goes off to infinity in both directions. The rest can get extremely weird as one of the complementary regions, in R<sup>2</sup> or H<sup>2</sup>, of one of some very strange closed subsets. In fact, *all* of them can be described as the universal Riemannian covering space of the complement of an *arbitrary* closed subset of R<sup>2</sup> or of H<sup>2</sup>. These are all (as Andrew Hwang has pointed out) not *complete*.

The Uniformization Theorem shows that each of these simply connected subsets of constant curvature K = 0 or K = -1 is, however, *conformally equivalent* to either R<sup>2</sup> or H<sup>2</sup>. (Given an arbitrary Riemannian metric on a simply connected non-compact surface, it is a difficult problem to decide whether it is conformally equivalent to R<sup>2</sup> or to H<sup>2</sup>.)